# What is the meaning of copying A of B?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> May is the earlier verb, showing up in manuscripts from the 8th century. It originally referred to having strength or power, and then very quickly developed a meaning that referred to ability. This particular meaning is no longer in current use, but we find a late representative of this use in Chaucer’s Canterbury Tales from 1395: “We mowen nat…It ouertake, it slit awey so faste” (“We may not overtake it, it slid away so fast”). May also developed a meaning referring to possibility, which we’re still familiar with today (“I may be able to have lunch with you this Thursday”), and the meaning that schoolteachers insist it has today–one that grants permission (“You may use the bathroom”). All four of these meanings were in use before 1000AD.

> Around that time, can came on the scene. It was a verb that originally meant “to know,” and then “to know how to do something,” and then “to have the ability to do something.” This last meaning, which showed up around 1300, was can’s first semantic overlap with may. The overlap continued: by 1500, both can and may were used to refer to ability and possibility. Given that there was already some overlap between the two words, it’s not surprising that by the end of the 1800s, can also came to mean “to have permission.” (If there’s anything surprising in that, it’s perhaps that it took so long for can to copy that meaning of may’s.)

: Here, “to copy that meaning of may’s” means “to copy the meaning of having permission from may’s one meaning of granting permission”? or “to copy that meaning of may’s” means “to copy the meaning of having permission among may’s different meanings”? Please answer me directly whether the former interpretation is adequate or the latter interpretation is adequate.

Comment: It's clumsily phrased. Personally, I'm not convinced the writer knows what he's talking about anyway - saying that ***it’s not surprising that*** (one word came to take on some or all meanings of another word) doesn't look like the kind of thing a professional linguist would say (imho, that kind of "semantic transfer" ***isn't*** meaningfully "predictable" - it just appears "logical, comprehensible" ***after the fact***).