# Can "copying A of B" be interpreted as 'copying A from B"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> May is the earlier verb, showing up in manuscripts from the 8th century. It originally referred to having strength or power, and then very quickly developed a meaning that referred to ability. This particular meaning is no longer in current use, but we find a late representative of this use in Chaucer’s Canterbury Tales from 1395: “We mowen nat…It ouertake, it slit awey so faste” (“We may not overtake it, it slid away so fast”). May also developed a meaning referring to possibility, which we’re still familiar with today (“I may be able to have lunch with you this Thursday”), and the meaning that schoolteachers insist it has today–one that grants permission (“You may use the bathroom”). All four of these meanings were in use before 1000AD.

> Around that time, can came on the scene. It was a verb that originally meant “to know,” and then “to know how to do something,” and then “to have the ability to do something.” This last meaning, which showed up around 1300, was can’s first semantic overlap with may. The overlap continued: by 1500, both can and may were used to refer to ability and possibility. Given that there was already some overlap between the two words, it’s not surprising that by the end of the 1800s, can also came to mean “to have permission.” (If there’s anything surprising in that, it’s perhaps that it took so long for can to copy that meaning of may’s.)

: Here, “to copy that meaning of may’s” means “to copy the meaning of having permission from may’s one meaning of granting permission”? or “to copy that meaning of may’s” means “to copy the meaning of having permission among may’s different meanings”(that is, "that meaning of may's" is such a phrase with double posseissive as a friend of mine)? Please answer me directly whether the former interpretation is adequate or the latter interpretation is adequate.

Comment: I think "having permission" means possessing permission that has already been given in this article, so I think "having permission" is not equivalent to "granting permission" in this article. After all, I think "having permission" is not one of may's four different meanings(that is, a meaning referring to having strength or power, a meaning referring to ability, a meaning referring to possibility, a meaning referring to granting permission).

Comment: Therefore, if "that meaning of may's" means not "that meaning from may's meaning" but "that meaning among may's four different meanings", because "that meaning of may's" means "a meaning referring to having permission among may's four different meanings(that is, a meaning referring to having strength or power, a meaning referring to ability, a meaning referring to possibility, a meaning referring to granting permission)", I think there is contradiction in the expression of "that meaning of may's" itself.

Comment: Can you (1) edit the question rather than explaining what it means in comments (2) cite where the quote is from, and (3) reproduce all formatting from the original in your question. The extract is hard to understand without it. If A copies B, it means that A takes on some attribute of B, or A does something that B does. Maybe draw a diagram or make a list if you're finding it hard to understand, because it is hard to understand.

Comment: The quote is from https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/when-to-use-can-and-may

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of copying A of B?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/338798/what-is-the-meaning-of-copying-a-of-b)

Comment: This is the third very similar question you have asked about this passage.  "It's surprising that it took _can_ so long to take on the meaning of 'have permission', similar to the same meaning of _may_' (which the author has just discussed).

Comment: Yes, this is the third very similar question I have asked about this passage. In fact, I have preference for the interpretation of copying the meaning of having permission from may's one meaning of granting permission, and my comments above are not the answer of my own question, What is the meaning of copying A of B? but the evidence of this preference.

Comment: But, because I'm not a native speaker, I can not help asking about the validity of my preference for that interpretation.

Comment: "It's surprising that it took can so long to take on the meaning of 'have permission', similar to the same meaning of may" - Does this interpretation imply that the interpretation of copying the meaning of having permission among may's different meanings is valid and a meaning of having permission is included in may's different meanings?

Comment: I quote - _the meaning that schoolteachers insist it has today–one that grants permission (“You may use the bathroom”)._

Comment: I don't understand why you have quoted this. Now I know "one that grants permission" doesn't refer to a granter of permission, and it specifically refers back to the meaning that schoolteachers insist may has today(that is, a meaning referring to granting permission).

Comment: You asked whether 'having permission' is one of the meanings of _may_. I reminded you of a sentence that indicates that it is.

Comment: Why do you think granting permission is equal to having permission? I don't understand the way of thinking of yours.